# local server not working. error connection refused. python 3 flask ubuntu 16

Tags: python, flask, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I am trying to run a flask app on my local machine but in my browsers I get error connection refused messages and sometimes i get the message in my terminal. The app did successfully create my table but I cannot view it in my browser. for host I have tried, localhost, 0.0.0.0 and 127.0.0.1 and for ports I have tried 5000, 8000, 8080, 8002 and I get the same error every time. I do have a VPN installed on my machine but it is turned off and I did a fresh restart without ever running the application and I still get the error. What is going wrong here?

I tried opening my firewall settings and setting new rules to allow incoming connections on ports in the 5000s and 8000s

I tried going to my proxy settings and enabling the proxy but setting it to not work on local connections and that didn't work.

I restarted my computer after making these changes and it had no effect.

I have also uninstalled my vpn application and restarted my computer and that didn't help.  So now i know that the vpn is not the problem.

When I ran netstat in cmd I did not see a connection for my localhost on port 5000

One thing to note is that I've tried so many different things and there were a few times I got the error connection refused in my terminal but I haVen't been seeing that in my terminal for a while now. That might be a sign of something. I can't seem to get that error to appear in my terminal again.

This is my code:

```
from flask import Flask
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
import os

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = 'postgresql+psycopg2://postgres:F00tBall@127.0.0.1:5432/example'
db = SQLAlchemy(app)

class Person(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'persons'
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = db.Column(db.String(), nullable=False)

db.create_all()

@app.route('/')
def index():
    return 'Hello '

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.secret_key = 'super_secret_key'
    app.debug = True
    #port = int(os.environ.get('PORT', 5000))
    app.run(host= '0.0.0.0', port=5000)
```

I have looked at every stackoverflow question relating to the connection refused error and cannot find a solution that works.

Comment: I can't reproduce your error. For me everything works fine with your code.

Comment: check if firewall is runnig `$ sudo ufw status` and then check apps list added to fire wall `sudo ufw app list` if you should add the rule for the port to firewall

Comment: I know the code is correct.  Its something to do with my computer.

Comment: the firewall is inactive

Comment: Run netstat -nlp | grep 5000 and see if you see your flask app listenning

Comment: i did and its not. how do i get it to listen